# Array's data is changed if I don't printf it

Tags: c, embedded, global-variables, cortex-m

I am writing a C program on Eclipse to communicate from my ARM Cortex M4-F microcontroller in I2C with its master, another MCU.
In my I2C library, I use a static global variable to store all the parameters of the communication (address, lenghts, data buffers). The issue is that a part (an array containing the data to be transmitted, which are 8 bits integers) of this variable gets modified when the interrupt (Start condition followed by the slave's address on the I2C bus) happens, even before executing the code I put the handler. It gets assigned to 8, whatever the initial value.
I tried to put breakpoints basically everywhere, and a watchpoint on the variable, the changes arises seemingly from nowhere, not in the while loop, and before the call to my_I2C_Handler(), so the interrupt is the cause apparently.
I also tried setting the variable as volatile, but that changed nothing.
I noticed one interesting thing: putting a printf of the array's data during my_I2C_Init() or my_SlaveAsync(), like so:

```
printf("%d\n", req.tx_data[0]);
```

corrects this problem, but why? I want to remove all prints after debugging.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "my_i2c.h"

void I2C1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    printf("\nI2C Interrupt\n");
    my_I2C_Handler(MXC_I2C1);    // MXC_I2C1 is a macro for the registry used
}

int main(void)
{
    int error = 0;
    printf("\nStarting I2C debugging\n");

    // Setup the I2C
    my_I2C_Shutdown(MXC_I2C1);
    my_I2C_Init(MXC_I2C1);

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C1_IRQn);    // Enable interrupt
    my_I2C_SlaveAsync(MXC_I2C1);  // Prepare to receive communication

    while (1)
    {
        LED_On(0);
        LED_Off(0);
    }
    printf("\nDone testing\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The structure of the request containing the parameters of the communication is like this:

```
typedef struct i2c_req i2c_req_t;
struct i2c_req {
    uint8_t addr;                       // I2C 7-bit Address
    unsigned tx_len;                    // Length of tx data
    unsigned rx_len;                    // Length of rx
    unsigned tx_num;                    // Number of tx bytes sent
    unsigned rx_num;                    // Number of rx bytes sent
    uint8_t *tx_data;                   // Data for mater write/slave read
    uint8_t *rx_data;                   // Data for master read/slave write
};
```

Is declared like so in the beginning of the file:

```
static i2c_req_t req;
```

and assigned this way in my_I2C_Init():

```
uint8_t rx[1] = {0};
uint8_t tx[1] = {12};

req.addr        = 0xAA;
req.tx_data     = tx;
req.tx_len      = 1;
req.rx_data     = rx;
req.rx_len      = 1;
req.tx_num      = 0;
req.rx_num      = 0;
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Seems like you have *undefined behavior* somewhere in your code, very likely in the parts you *don't* show us. Like for example where do you define the `rx` and `tx` arrays? Are they *local* inside the `my_I2C_Init` function? And do you ever write more than one byte to those array (use indexes other than `0`)?

Comment: You say that you have trouble with a global variable but you don't show *any code* that deals with it. What's to understand from this? Nothing really. Add any relevant part of the code that handles the global object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, 'rx' and 'tx' aret local in the init function.
I tried putting more than one element, nothing changes, an 8 still comes up

Comment: Why do you have an array of length 1 as data buffer? And how do you handle re-entrancy between the ISR and the caller? You show nothing of that.

Comment: @Eak'Lon They obviously can't be local variables. And as a rule of thumb, all data buffers in embedded systems should have static storage duration.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I show you every occurence of the modifications (in this case just the assignation) of the global variable, req. Later in the code, I use it again to send the data, but the change happens before that.

Comment: @Eak'Lon sorry I was not clear. What I was suggesting is to add the actual code inside those functions, if it makes sense and is not long enough. Or at least integrate it in the main code snippet.

Comment: @Lundin It's for the example's sake, but the length of the array will be variable later.  I'll try to make these static

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Is is quite long, but I'll shorten it as much as possible and integrate it in the post. Is is mostly I2C registers being modified to initialize the communication

Comment: @Lundin Your rule pf thumb worked! I put `rx` and `tx` as static globals, and now the data doesn't get modified. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another rule of thumb: Don't do anything that can cause or wait for interrupts inside your interrupt handler, or just is slow. That typically includes all kinds of I/O (like calling `printf`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, I'll remember that if there is an unexpected issue. Either way, I'll remove all prints when debugging is finished.

Comment: @Lundin You can post your comment as a reply, I'll accept it

Comment: Nah this should rather be closed as a dupe to thousand other questions that use pointers to local variables...